# How to search a commit in git web interface

Tags: git

How can search a commit using  git web interface.

For example, here is a git web http://git.kernel.org/?p=git/git.git;a=summary.

It has a commit id like '8ead1bfe111085ef1ad7759e67340f074996b244'

http://git.kernel.org/?p=git/git.git;a=commit;h=8ead1bfe111085ef1ad7759e67340f074996b244

but why when I go to 'http://git.kernel.org/?p=git/git.git;a=summary', select 'commit' and enter '8ead1bfe111085ef1ad7759e67340f074996b244', it said 'No match'?

http://git.kernel.org/?p=git%2Fgit.git&a=search&h=HEAD&st=commit&s=8ead1bfe111085ef1ad7759e67340f074996b244

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I can tell, you can't do that with gitweb. I suppose they reasoned that you could just paste the commit hash into the URL yourself, as the `h=` parameter?

Note that at least gitweb will take an arbitrary committish for the h parameter, as in http://git.kernel.org/?p=git/git.git;a=commit;h=v1.8.0.

According to gitweb's [search help](http://git.kernel.org/?p=git/git.git;a=search_help), when you select "Commit", then

> The commit messages and authorship information will be scanned for the given pattern.

Comment: Thanks. Can you please tell me what is the purpose of the search box with selection 'Commit' ?